# Why isn't this question closed as too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm sorry for finger pointing, but [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91266/how-do-backdoors-work) is the architype of a bad question showing no research whatsoever. Why isn't it closed as too broad?

I just can't resist:

```
list=`read "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)#Software_vulnerabilities"`
for item in ${list} do
    post_question "How do $(item)s work?"
done
```

EDIT: The question is on hold now (phew!), so let me reformulate: what can be done to prevent such questions from staying so long? **Or am I out of line here and the community actually wants questions like this?** I mean, it got upvoted by 11 people, edited and answered twice. This means at least 14 people have paid close attention to this question and decided it was worth the upvote and their effort in editing and answering it.

Comment: Why dont you vote to close? Or at least, flag it for a mod's attention... Simpler. :-)

Comment: I did. I'm just surprised the question is still there. Am I the only one to see the problem?

Comment: No, but that's not the way the process works. Now, it is closed, but these things usually do take more than a few minutes, especially over night.

Comment: The answers and comments cover why it took a little while to close the question.  As far as why it got upvoted by so many people: one possible answer is that it was listed on Hot Network Questions, which has the potential to distort vote counts.  (See, e.g., http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1590/971 and http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1835/971.)

Answer (score 3):

It takes five close votes (or one moderator's supervote, but they don't normally do that) to close a question.  In any given day, there are maybe a half-dozen users reviewing the close-vote queue, so it takes time to accumulate the votes needed.